# Getting a constant answer while finding patterns with neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to find patterns in a large dataset using the neuralnet package.

My data file looks something like this (30,204,447 rows) :

```
id.company,EPS.or.Sales,FQ.or.FY,fiscal,date,value

000001,EPS,FY,2001,20020201,-5.520000
000001,SAL,FQ,2000,20020401,70.300003
000001,SAL,FY,2001,20020325,49.200001
000002,EPS,FQ,2008,20071009,-4.000000
000002,SAL,FY,2008,20071009,1.400000
```

I have split this initial file into four new files for annual/quarterly sales/EPS and it is on those files that I want to use neural networks to see if I can use the variables id.company, fiscal and date in the case below to predict the annual sales results.

To do so, I have written the following code:

```
dataset <- read.table("fy_sal_data.txt",header=T, sep="\t") #my file doesn't actually use comas as separators

#extract training set and testing set
trainset <- dataset[1:1000, ]
testset <- dataset[1001:2000, ]

#building the NN
ann <- neuralnet(value ~ id.company + fiscal + date, trainset, hidden = 3,
             lifesign="minimal", threshold=0.01)

#testing the output
temp_test <- subset(testset, select=c("id.company", "fiscal", "date"))
ann.results <- compute(ann, temp_test)

#display the results
cleanoutput <- cbind(testset$value, as.data.frame(ann.results$net.result))
colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Expected Output", "NN Output")

head(cleanoutput, 30)
```

Now my problem is that the compute function returns a constant answer no matter the inputs of the testing set.

```
     Expected Output   NN Output
1001     2006.500000 1417.796651
1002     2009.000000 1417.796651
1003     2006.500000 1417.796651
1004     2002.500000 1417.796651
```

---

I am very new to R and its neural networks packages but I have found online that some of the reasons for such results can be either:

- an insufficient number of training examples (here I'm using a thousand ones but I've also tried using a million rows and the results were the same, only it took 4h to train)
- or an error in the formula.

I am sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: You might try using the `rep` parameter in `compute()` and `neuralnet()` with a fitting value.

Comment: I have tried setting it to 3 but the results and the error remain the same.

Comment: Anyone ? I couldn't find anything online tto help me so I've been stuck on that for two days.

Comment: I can't offer specific help as I'm not much familiar with R. But when stuck, try to simplify your data. It really helps identifying the issue. Start with XOR or sth well-defined

Comment: I tried using three data frames containing random values as inputs and have the network give the sum of those variables but here again, it gives me a constant value so there is definitely something wrong with my code... just can't figure out what (though I'm suspecting it has to do with the way I write my formula parameter in neuralnet() ). Thanks for the help !